# Apache Spark DecimalType uses BigDecimal setScale that rounds up

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdecimal

I have an input table with one row that I'm trying to read from, where the column value I'm interested in is 0.070070073108537356 (20 digits total, 18 after the decimal point)

I set my read preferences to read with Spark `DecimalType(precision = 38, scale = 18)`, the datatype that represents `java.math.BigDecimal` values. When I read this value, I end up getting 0.070070073108537360 which has a scale of 18 but seems like it's rounding up the number to create a new decimal with the same scale but a rounded up value.

I thought `BigDecimal.setScale(18)` would give me the exact same number as my input because it has 18 digits after the decimal point.

Can anyone explain why BigDecimal rounds up?

Seems like it's an off by 1 error, and using a scale of 19 would give me the number I want.

Update: After some testing, this rounding problem doesn't seem to happen if I use a decimal with a scale of 16 or less. Once I bump it up to a scale of 17 with a decimal having 17 digits after the decimal, it starts rounding.